# RabbitMQ and Pika

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

I'm using python lib pika, fow work with rabbitmq.
RabbitMq runnning and listen `0.0.0.0:5672`, I try connect to him from another server, and I get exception:

> socket.timeout: timed out

Python code using from official doc `RabbitMQ(Hello, World)`
I was try disable iptables.
But if I run script with host `"localhost"`, all good work.
My /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config

```
[
  {rabbit, [
    {tcp_listeners,[{"0.0.0.0",5672}]}
  ]}
].
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='192.168.10.150', port=5672, virtual_host='/', credentials=pika.credentials.PlainCredentials('user', '123456')))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='task_queue', durable=True)

message = "Hello World!"
channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='task_queue',
                      body=message,
                      properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                         delivery_mode = 2, # make message persistent
                      ))
print " [x] Sent %r" % (message,)
connection.close()
```

Comment: Can you post the python client code you are using to connect to the remote rabbit server?  Do you turn off iptables on both client and server?  I'm assuming this is Linux, what distribution?

Comment: iptables turn off on client and server. Debian 7.

Comment: I find in log file: access to vhost '/' refused for user 'user'"

Comment: Do you still have the guest user active on the server?  Check your server permissions for `user`.  Othewise, try `guest` user with `guest` password.

Comment: I find answer, I tune access to user

Comment: Would you please check port of that server? (that should be open).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are connecting from another server, you should check your machine`s firewall settings